# In a graph where every vertex is odd, for any partition the parity of number of edges joining the partitions equals the size of partition.

Tags: graph-theory

Let G be a graph in which every vertex has odd degree. Let $\{V_1, V_2\}$ be a partition of $V(G)$. Denote $[V_1, V_2]$ by the set of edges of G joining $V_1$ and $V_2$. I need to prove that $|V_1|$ and $|[V_1, V_2]|$ have the same parity.

I was given the hint to use the handshaking lemma but I'm absolutely stuck on where to go in this question. First, I'm not sure if $V_1 \cup V_2$ must equal $V(G)$.
I tried drawing some examples to see and it seems like its true even if the partitions don't include all vertices of G.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If $V_1\cup V_2\ne V(G)$, then it's possible that $|V_1|$ and $|V_2|$ have different parity, so one of them doesn't have the same parity as $|[V_1,V_2]|$. So, yes, the condition is necessary.

Comment: Can you prove that the sum of the degrees of the vertices in $V_1$ has the same parity as $|V_1|$?  Can you prove that the sum of the degrees of the vertices in $V_1$ is equal to the number of edges in $[V_1,V_2]$ plus twice the number of edges with both endpoints in $V_1$?

Comment: By the way there's something funny about your terminology. You say "edges joining the partitions"? What partitions? Are $V_1$ and $V_2$ partitions? And $\{V_1,V_2\}$ is also a partition?